# Why we need to install Workloads from VS Installer if we can download packages from Nuget Package Manager?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, fcl

We can download several workloads (which are parts of FCL) from Visual Studio Installer such as "Data storage and processing". But we can also download EntityFramework.Core Package from NuGet Package Manager and work with it and connect to DB properly. In that case why we need to download workloads from VS Installer? Are they just for templates or what?

I have searched about it and found that options that we can download from VS Installer are parts of FCL. But for example, if we can connect to the DB and use it through downloading "EntityFramework.Core" Package from NuGet Package Manager, why we need to install "Data storage and processing "from VS Installer?

Answer (score 0):

The Visual Studio Installer and NuGet are designed for two completely different purposes.

The Visual Studio Installer installs Visual Studio and components of Visual Studio. A workload is a set of components. Some components are members of multiple workloads. A component typically adds some functionality to Visual Studio but a component can also be something that supports functionality in Visual Studio.

The set of components in the "Data storage and processing" workload is documented. As an example, for VS Enterprise see [Data storage and processing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-enterprise?view=vs-2022#data-storage-and-processing). Note that one of the components in the workload is NuGet. To be able to use NuGet in the Visual Studio UI, the NuGet component has to be installed.

NuGet operates on Projects. NuGet package references are not 'global'. When you use NuGet to install a NuGet package, it is related to the project. A NuGet package is commonly a library.

The "Data storage and processing" workload is installing tools in Visual Studio that support browsing and connecting to databases independent of any project or solution. It is also installing NuGet.

Within a given project NuGet can be used to add packages to the project.